# Cambiar el color a los datos dentro de un value de select2

Tags: html5

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('detalleingreso_id', 'PRODUCTO DISPONIBLES') }}
        <select name="detalleingreso_id" id="detalleingreso_id" class="form-control select2">

            @foreach($data3 as $row)
                <option value="{{ $row->id }}" >{{ strtoupper($row->producto->proveedor->nombre)}} | {{ strtoupper($row->producto->nombre)}} | {{ strtoupper($row->pv_publico)}} | {{ strtoupper($row->producto->cantidad)}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

Como puedo colocar colores a cada dato dentro de mi option por ejemplo:

```
 {{ strtoupper($row->pv_publico)}}
```

que sea azul y lo demás negro

Comment: Es decir cada *option* deseas que este con un color distinto la letra ?

Comment: ¿Por qué son las `@`, usas algún framework? Deberías indicarlo poniendo la etiqueta respectiva, pulsa [edit] para ello. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano está utilizando blade de Laravel.

Comment: aquí tienes un enlace donde hacen lo que estás buscando: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748026/how-to-change-font-color-of-select2-control-using-css 
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: si quiero colocar un color distinto a cada valor dentro del option